# Put static files on "/" in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, static-files

I'm a Yesod beginner, and want to build a web site which mainly constructed with static files.

It's required to put static files on `/`, and dynamic page on `/foo`.

So I prepared static files in `static` directory
(e.g., static/index.html, static/img/bar.gif, static/css/baz.css, ...),
 and wrote `config/routes` as follows:

```
/    StaticR Static getStatic
/foo FooR    GET    POST
```

Ghc claims that

```
Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
 Overlapping routes: 
("StaticR","FooR")
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try changing the order of declared routes since I think the static route subsumes the `FooR` in your current case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ms's comment is correct: you should put `FooR` before `StaticR`. In addition, you'll need to turn off overlap checking. The easiest way is probably to use `parseRoutesFileNoCheck` instead of `parseRoutesFile` (or `parseRoutesNoCheck` instead of `parseRoutes` if you're using the quasiquoter).

Comment: There's no error, but it seems that `FooR` can't refference static files in hamlet as `@{StaticR resource_foo_css}`.
I have `/static/resource/foo.css`.

Comment: I found a setting `staticRoot` was set `/static`, so I repaired it.